# Access Database: How to import the queried data from SQL database/table

Tags: sql, ms-access, import

I have set up an Access database and now I am trying to import data into the Access database table from the SQL database. The Access database table is empty right now and I am trying to import the data from the SQL database with only a key value. For example, I only want to import the data that meets the following criteria.

```
Select * from myTable where UserID = 1234
```

I have set up the ODBC link to the table. I have been looking for ways to do this, but haven't found anything good.

***Update***

Figured it out and for anyone who might need to know how to do this, here are the steps.

```
 Create -> Query design -> Select the source table -> Select the desired columns -> Click "Append" -> Select the destination table -> Enter criteria -> click "Run"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an Access `Append Query` which uses the ODBC linked SQL Server table and writes the data to the Access Table. In the query, make sure you include your `Where` clause